# Tool to highlight text in WordPress page and provide additional text on hover

Tags: plugins, content

I'm looking for a tool within WordPress to provide genius.com/hypothes.is style annotations to page content. Like Modern Footnotes, a plugin that displays additional text on hover - but over highlighted text instead of over a Footnote. I don't need the ability for other people to annotation, just the WordPress admin.

Use case: I'm a songwriter and I'd like to post my lyrics, but with annotations. Similar to the way lyrics appear on Genius.com. But only a WordPress admin needs to be able to edit them.

I've foundn annotatejs.org/hypothes.is, but those require third-party storage backends and are geared around community editing. Genius.com is also geared around community editing and requires use of their web service. The Modern Footnotes plugin looks so close, but it displays things as footnotes instead of allowing the ability to highlight text - which gives it a very academic feel.

Any suggestions? I think "annotation" is the right word, but lots of different things come up when I try to search for that.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, [Tooltip CK](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/tooltip-ck/) is actually very close, with some custom CSS to style it more like a text highlight.

Unlike other Tooltip plugins, it allows you to edit Tooltip text inline (rather than treating it like a glossary with another content type). Unlike most footnote plugins, it doesn't appear at the bottom or use superscript. Unlike most annotation plugins, it doesn't require a third-party service or assume community editing.